# Is there a way to keyframe time stretching?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, keyframes, timeline, frame-rate

Is there a way to keyframe time streching? I'm trying to make an animation with a fluid sim, and want to have a "slow-mo" effect without having to render it twice and slice it together. Any ideas?

Comment: you can do this in the vse...but depending on your frame rate and your rate of slow-mo it might begin to "flicker" but if you slow down only a bit you can hardly see it

Comment: @Chris I'm using flip fluids and after a bit of digging found out you can keyframe the fluid sim in there, so I just slowed down the animation to match. How I have my scene set up is fluid falling into a glass, then having that glass move, but the fluid doesn't actually move with the glass, it just acts like the glass is still in the same spot.

Comment: is the glass the domain or an effector object?

Comment: @Chris the glass is an obstacle with the domain surrounding it. Since the glass is thin, I added a cube with the glass cut out of it to add more of a wall around it so the fluid stays in, and parented that cube to the glass so it moves with it.

Comment: on the obstacle in the properties: mesh data export: did you check "export animated mesh" on your glass?

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome